# Place a Variable Value Within an Array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, pdo

I am trying to place cleaned form data into a MySQL database using PDO. However, I cannot seem to get my data array to work properly. Is it possible for a variable to be placed within an array? If not, what are my options? The simplified code is below:

```
$DBH = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME,USER,PASS, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
$DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$fname = $clean['fname'];
$lname = $clean['lname'];
$data = array( 'FirstName' => $fname, 'LastName' => $lname);
$STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO " .DB_TABLE. " (FirstName, LastName) value (:FirstName, :LastName)");
$STH->execute($data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is, though your `$data` should be like this:

```
$data = array( ':FirstName' => $fname, ':LastName' => $lname);
```